# Select max by property from list of objects

Tags: linq, list, select

I have some class and list of objects of that class.

```
class Map
{
    public string Name;
    public int Distance;
    // ...
}

List<Map> MapList = new List<Map>();

MapList.Add(new Map("Name 1", 20));
MapList.Add(new Map("Name 2", 75));
MapList.Add(new Map("Name 3", 50));

int max = MapList.?????
// expected result: 75
```

I'm new in LINQ. The question is: how can I select maximum `Distance` value from my `MapList`?

Comment: `int max = MapList.Max(m => m.Distance);`

Comment: @Slai Usually I say this the other way around but this is an answer and not a comment ;) Add answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
int max = MapList.Max(i => i.Distance);
// Or
int max = MapList.OrderByDescending(i => i.Distance).Select(i => i.Distance).FirstOrDefault();
```